# Restore SharePoint List from STP as the List already exists, Without creating newer one

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, stp

I'm using SharePoint here I have created a backup of SharePoint List in STP format. Now I've few changes to my list and I don't want that changes. Therefore I wanted to revert my changes in the list from the backup of STP file. I've uploaded the stp file to List template gallery, and in the site content inside create app option it is not allowing to create list with the same name as the list already exists. So what should I do I wanted to restore my changes, how can I do that?

I don't want to create list with newer name or don't want to delete my existing list because it will surly affect my lookup columns.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am using SharePoint, there is no way using which we can Undo or Redo the list structures. The only option is

1. Take back up of your latest list with data
2. Create new list with some Temporary name using the template stored using step-1
3. Delete the existing list
4. Create a new list with the template that you want to have
5. Use Datasheet view to copy and paste the data into the new list created from that temporary list or you can create a small utility C# console application to copy the data from old list to new list.

Let me know if you have any confusion